# QoS and other way to optimize speed on network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, qos

I have some weird network issues. I'm  running on 2 VM's email verifications and my whole network becomes laggy and loosely from it. It shouldn't use high bandwidth its more like sending a lots of small request and waiting for the result. My VPS remote connection keep loosing a few times in every minutes which is connected to my server through VPN to work with files and SQL Server.  After 5 minutes it can't reach it although it is still connected.  Facebook, Youtube, Curse voice, online gaming, everything online is loosing connection for a few seconds. I set up QoS high priority on my router to my laptop (I work and control everything from my laptop) medium priority on my IBM server both network interface IPs and a 25-25% bandwidth limitation to the VMs which are causing the lags but I got the same speed with that like without it. When I gaming that is seems alright now but other applications still loose for a few second always.

I have a:

- Superhub in modem mode
- a Belkin 7800n router
- D-Link 24 port switch
- 152/12mb internet connection

I have a DC controller on the IBM as a VM(handles DHCP,DNS,AD). So what are my limitation factors and what causing the lags? There is any software out of there for fix this? What shall I look for? My guess is the router is not good enough if it then the NETGEAR Nighthawk R7000 should handle it?

Any advice please?

QoS config:

[image: pic]

Comment: Just for clarification where are the two VM's sending small requests too outside of the LAN, across the VPN, etc.?

Comment: No. from the local network. I ust have the VPN to speed up the whole process and add more vps to speed up everything.